# I get the error "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence." working on my codes

Tags: conv-neural-network

I have the following code snippet. All sections works well except the #Setting up Scalars section

```
# Fitting in the columns
    column_x=df['tcpsck']
    column_y=df['NoRTPPkts']

# Setting the sequence
```

input_seq_length = 70
target_seq_length = 30

```
# Create lists to store input and target sequences
X_data = []
Y_data = []

# Convert the lists to NumPy arrays
X_data = np.array(X_data, dtype=object)
Y_data = np.array(Y_data, dtype=object)

# Setting up the Scalars
scaler_x = MaxAbsScaler()
scaler_y = MaxAbsScaler()

X_data = scaler_x.fit_transform(X_data)
Y_data = scaler_y.fit_transform(Y_data)

*I get this error on this section*

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[27], line 4
      1 scaler_x = MaxAbsScaler()
      2 scaler_y = MaxAbsScaler()
----> 4 X_data = scaler_x.fit_transform(X_data)
      5 Y_data = scaler_y.fit_transform(Y_data)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_set_output.py:140, in _wrap_method_output.<locals>.wrapped(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
    138 @wraps(f)
    139 def wrapped(self, X, *args, **kwargs):
--> 140     data_to_wrap = f(self, X, *args, **kwargs)
    141     if isinstance(data_to_wrap, tuple):
    142         # only wrap the first output for cross decomposition
    143         return (
    144             _wrap_data_with_container(method, data_to_wrap[0], X, self),
    145             *data_to_wrap[1:],
    146         )

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:878, in TransformerMixin.fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    874 # non-optimized default implementation; override when a better
    875 # method is possible for a given clustering algorithm
    876 if y is None:
    877     # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation)
--> 878     return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
    879 else:
    880     # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)
    881     return self.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_data.py:1169, in MaxAbsScaler.fit(self, X, y)
   1167 # Reset internal state before fitting
   1168 self._reset()
-> 1169 return self.partial_fit(X, y)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\_data.py:1195, in MaxAbsScaler.partial_fit(self, X, y)
   1192 self._validate_params()
   1194 first_pass = not hasattr(self, "n_samples_seen_")
-> 1195 X = self._validate_data(
   1196     X,
   1197     reset=first_pass,
   1198     accept_sparse=("csr", "csc"),
   1199     dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES,
   1200     force_all_finite="allow-nan",
   1201 )
   1203 if sparse.issparse(X):
   1204     mins, maxs = min_max_axis(X, axis=0, ignore_nan=True)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:565, in BaseEstimator._validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    563     raise ValueError("Validation should be done on X, y or both.")
    564 elif not no_val_X and no_val_y:
--> 565     X = check_array(X, input_name="X", **check_params)
    566     out = X
    567 elif no_val_X and not no_val_y:

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py:879, in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator, input_name)
    877         array = xp.astype(array, dtype, copy=False)
    878     else:
--> 879         array = _asarray_with_order(array, order=order, dtype=dtype, xp=xp)
    880 except ComplexWarning as complex_warning:
    881     raise ValueError(
    882         "Complex data not supported\n{}\n".format(array)
    883     ) from complex_warning

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_array_api.py:185, in _asarray_with_order(array, dtype, order, copy, xp)
    182     xp, _ = get_namespace(array)
    183 if xp.__name__ in {"numpy", "numpy.array_api"}:
    184     # Use NumPy API to support order
--> 185     array = numpy.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    186     return xp.asarray(array, copy=copy)
    187 else:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

# How I solve this guys? Thanks

I tried using minscalars against the maxAbsscalars but it wasn't working.
```

I have tried troubleshooting numerously with no success. The data that has been fed is from a two column dataset of corresponding values. The dataset has non-spatial data. All I am trying to do is to fit train and test the data using CNN. I am not entirely familiar with the min and maxAB scalars. I think problem has something to do with arrays but I don;t know how to bypass that.

Comment: The `X_data` and `Y_data` arrays have a length of zero, which will raise an error when scaling. Arrays need to have dimensions of `(number of samples, number of features)`. Suppose you have two features (two columns), and 10 such samples - in this case `X_data` should therefore have dimensions of `10 x 2`. The question is why does the code you posted try scaling an empty array - did you mean to fill it with some data before scaling?